# Prove that there is a basis for the $n$th degree polynomial vector space consisting $only$ of $n$th degree polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I tried looking around for an answer to this question, but I couldn't find anything specific enough. I'm thinking I need to use either Cartesian products or subspace sums to produce such a vector space, however I'm still fuzzy on how to actually implement it.

Any help would be great!

Comment: What is the $n$-th degree polynomial vector space? Is that the vector space of polynomials (coefficients in some field) whose degree is at most $n$?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding. My text uses the notation [$x$;$n$], without any explanation as to how it should be read, unfortunately.

Comment: Hint: if $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis for a vector space, then so is $\{v_1+v_n,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

We know that $\{1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^n\}$ is a basis for your space. But then $$\{1+x^n, x+x^n, x^2+x^n, \ldots, 2x^n\}$$

is also a basis for your space.

Answer (score 0):

Pick any basis $f_1, \ldots, f_n, f_{n+1}$. At least one of these polynomials must have degree exactly $n$, otherwise $x^n$ would not be in the generated subspace. 
WLOG $\deg f_1 =n$. 
If some of the other basis vectors have smaller degree, add $f_1$ to them (and only to those with degree strictly less than $n$). 
That yields a solution you were looking for.